# Spring: Define AbstractRoutingDataSource which's targetDataSources are filled from seperate (H2-)DataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I try to setup a spring/spring-boot project which has an AbstractRoutingDataSource whichs targetDataSources should be filled from a separate DataSource (actually embedded H2-DataSource).

I have tried many different things (configuring multiple EntityManagerFactories and TransactionManagers) but somewhere I always either get a circular reference or the Repository-Bean which should provide the details for my targetDataSources is null when autowiring it into the RoutingDataSource.

The thing seems to be that I can't use any DataSource dependency inside initialization of my RoutingDataSource, because it's a DataSource itself and therefore will be created before any Repository-Beans.

Can you give me a hint how the approach would look to configure

- A H2-Datasource which is initialized first
- A Repository for this (and only this) H2-DataSource
- A RoutingDataSource which depends on the Repository and loads its targetDataSources from it

Comment: do you really need a repository? Sounds like you need to execute just one statement. I'd consider switching to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and create that directly with your datasource.

Comment: That was one possibility I thought about myself - still wonder if it's possible to have this kind of dependency. Especially because it's not only one statement because you might want to insert new items to the H2-Database or update them